# “In a fact" or "In the fact"?

Tags: listening

[sound track](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/in-the-fact)
I'm practicing this listening stuff. It seems to be "in a fact" or "in the fact" at the beginning of the sentence. I'm not sure. I searched both. They're all not so common.

Comment: He clearly says **in effect**.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, Yes. I have wanted to accept the answer. But there is a code that I can't accept an answer immediately. So I forgot this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I heard this:

> So, **in effect**, ...

Comment: When I saw the answer just after you postted it, I wanted to accept it. But I can't .. some rule that I can't accept an answer immediately. But, after that, I forgot to accept it until someone added a comment that remind me.